# Como listar usuários e suas "Roles"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Olá!
Preciso listar o nível de acesso dos usuários na minha página de Consulta de Usuários. Mas não consigo acessar os dados da Role através do User. A entidade User possui o atributo Role que está mapeada com a anotação ManyToMany, assim:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Thymeleaf:

```
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="lista">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>E-mail (Nome de usuário)</th>
                                    <th>Nível de Acesso</th>
                                    <th>Deletar</th>
                                 </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="user : ${user}">
                                    <td th:text="${user.id}"> </td>
                                    <td th:text="${user.name} + '  ' + ${user.lastName}"> </td>
                                    <td th:text="${user.email}"> </td>
                                    <td th:text="${user.roles}"></td>
```

Mas quando tento retornar o nome da Role na minha view, fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para mostrar a Role de cada usuário nessa tabela?

Saída do hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_4_, user0_.active as active2_4_, user0_.email as email3_4_, user0_.last_name as last_nam4_4_, user0_.name as name5_4_, user0_.password as password6_4_ from users user0_ where user0_.email=? 
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_4_, user0_.active as active2_4_, user0_.email as email3_4_, user0_.last_name as last_nam4_4_, user0_.name as name5_4_, user0_.password as password6_4_ from users user0_ order by user0_.user_id asc limit ?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_3_0_, role1_.role_id as role_id1_2_1_, role1_.role as role2_2_1_ from user_role roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.role_id where roles0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_3_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_3_0_, role1_.role_id as role_id1_2_1_, role1_.role as role2_2_1_ from user_role roles0_ inner join role role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.role_id where roles0_.user_id=?
```

Comment: Qual é o seu problema?

Comment: @dhb Meu problema é o relatado na foto acima: Não consigo listar as Roles dos usuários, o Thymeleaf retorna essa string da foto... O que eu quero é através do usuário eu retornar o nome da Role que foi atribuída a ele, no caso existem duas cadastradas ADMIN e SUPPORT. Eu quero mostrar a role de cada usuário na tabela da foto acima.

Comment: Você não consegue fazer algo como ${user.role.name}?
Outra opção seria implementar o método toString da classe Role.

Comment: @dhb Não consigo, quando tento retorna o valor da foto. Eu editei a pergunta e coloquei mais detalhes agora.

Comment: Agora acho que agora entendi, `${user.roles}` retorna uma lista de ROLE e você está tentando mostrar a lista então não aprestará de forma correta, ou você itera essa lista assim como fez com os usuários `th:each="user : ${user}` ou cria um método para retornar uma string das ROLES concatenadas.
Espero ter conseguido explicar.

Comment: Entendi, mas eu preciso mostrar a Role pertencente a cada usuário. Não tem como eu acessar os atributos da Role pelo relacionamento? Exemplo, eu tenho outra entidade Atendimento e Cliente eu consigo listar os dados do cliente na consulta de Atendimento assim -> <td th:text="${atendimento.cliente.razaoSocial}"></td>

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65501/discussion-between-dhb-and-cisino-junior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como é uma lista de **ROLE** você deve iterar, tente algo como:

```
<span th:each="role: ${user.roles}"> 
<td th:text="${role.role}"></td> 
</span>
```